# How to bind rows of dataframes in separate elements within a list of lists

Tags: r, list, element, rbind

Let's suppose I have a list of lists as follows:

```
set.seed(111)
lst_1 = rep(list(list()), 3) 

lst_1[[1]] = list(data.frame(rnorm(5)), data.frame(rnorm(5)))
lst_1[[2]] = list(data.frame(rnorm(5)), data.frame(rnorm(5)))
lst_1[[3]] = list(data.frame(rnorm(5)), data.frame(rnorm(5)))
```

where each list element (1, 2 and 3) is a list which contains two data.frames.

How can I sequentially bind the rows of the first `data.frame` within each (sub)list? i.e. `lst_1[[1]][[1]]` + `lst_1[[2]][[1]]` + `lst_1[[3]][[1]]`, and eventually do the same for the second `data.frame`?

Here is my desired output, which is achieved manually with a for loop, however my real list of lists is much larger:

```
lst_out = rep(list(list()), 2) 

for (i in 1:2) {
lst_out[[i]] = rbind(lst_1[[1]][[i]], lst_1[[2]][[i]], lst_1[[3]][[i]])
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm interpreting correctly, the base R solution should be pretty straight forward. `Map` the `rbind` function over each part of the 3 inputs in `lst_1`:

```
do.call(Map, c(rbind, lst_1))
```

This is a slightly obscured way of calling the expanded `Map` line of:

```
Map(rbind, lst_1[[1]], lst_1[[2]], lst_1[[3]])
```

Which starts to look a lot like your original `for` loop, and gives the same result as doing it via `do.call`:

```
identical(
  do.call(Map, c(rbind, lst_1)),
  Map(rbind, lst_1[[1]], lst_1[[2]], lst_1[[3]])
)
#[1] TRUE
```

Checks out with the intended result too:

```
identical(lst_out, do.call(Map, c(rbind, lst_1)))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I'm new to R and I'm struggling to understand `do.call(Map, c(rbind, lst_1))
` . Could you you explain what's going on in this call, please? How does `do.call` convert lst_1 into a list of arguments?

Comment: @PabloRod - To run `Map` normally, you need to specify `Map(f, ...)` where `f=` is a `f`unction and `...` is any number of arguments which get fed into that `f`unction. A simple example would be `Map(paste, 1:3, 7:9)` . `do.call` just abstracts this one more level, piecing together a 'call' like `do.call(what=Map, args=c(paste, list(1:3,7:9)))` . The `what=` is the function that gets called, and the `args=` (arguments), are the sequential list of everything you'd normally put inside `Map()` as comma-separated parts.

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest way is to simply `purrr::transpose` the list, so that instead of three sublists with two dataframe elements, you have two sublists with three dataframe elements. This means that the dataframes to bind are all in the same sublist, so iteration is much simpler and we can `map` over the main list. See below, noting that you can just load `purrr` as `dplyr::bind_rows` is just a bit faster and `tibble::glimpse` is for printing only.

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(111)
lst_1 = rep(list(list()), 3) 

lst_1[[1]] = list(data.frame(rnorm(5)), data.frame(rnorm(5)))
lst_1[[2]] = list(data.frame(rnorm(5)), data.frame(rnorm(5)))
lst_1[[3]] = list(data.frame(rnorm(5)), data.frame(rnorm(5)))

lst_1 %>%
  transpose %>%
  map(bind_rows) %>%
  glimpse
#> List of 2
#>  $ :'data.frame':    15 obs. of  1 variable:
#>   ..$ rnorm.5.: num [1:15] 0.235 -0.331 -0.312 -2.302 -0.171 ...
#>  $ :'data.frame':    15 obs. of  1 variable:
#>   ..$ rnorm.5.: num [1:15] 0.14 -1.497 -1.01 -0.948 -0.494 ...
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Which I think is just `pmap(lst_1, bind_rows)` or `lst_1 %>% pmap(bind_rows)` if we're piping.

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution

```
set.seed(111)
lst_1 <- rep(list(list()), 3) 

lst_1[[1]] <- list(data.frame(rnorm(5)), data.frame(rnorm(5)))
lst_1[[2]] <- list(data.frame(rnorm(5)), data.frame(rnorm(5)))
lst_1[[3]] <- list(data.frame(rnorm(5)), data.frame(rnorm(5)))

lst_out_2 <- list()

for (i in 1:2) { 
  lst_out_2[[i]] <- do.call('rbind', sapply(lst_1, `[`, i))
}
```